# Is there a way to return either a new object or reference to existing object from a function?

Tags: c++, gcc, parameter-passing, c++17, return-by-reference

I am trying to write a function, which can either return a reference to an existing object passed as a first argument (if it is in correct state) or create and return a new object using literal passed as a second argument (default).

It would be even better if a function could take not only literal, but also another existing object as a second (default) argument and return a reference to it.

Below is a trivial implementation, but it does a lot of unneeded work:

1. If called with lvalue as a second (default) argument, it calls a copy constructor of an argument, that is selected for return. Ideally a reference to an object should be returned.
2. If called with literal as a second (default) argument, it calls constructor, copy constructor and destructor, even if second (default) argument is not selected for return. It would be better if an object is constructed and returned as rvalue reference without calling copy constructor or destructor.

```
std::string get_or_default(const std::string& st, const std::string& default_st) {
    if (st.empty()) return default_st
    else return st;
}
```

Is there a way to accomplish this more efficiently, while still keeping simple for caller? If I am correct, this requires a function to change return type based on run-time decision made inside a function, but I cannot think of a simple solution for caller.

Comment: If you want to return a reference, why isn't the return type `const std::string&`?

Comment: Sure you can have the cake, and also eat it. It just requires a little bit more work: returning a variant of either a string or a `std::ref` to a string. Sure, it's quite an overkill, but it'll get the job done, albeit in a rather verbose, slightly convoluted way that will require additional work by each caller to properly process the result.

Comment: @Rualark: This question seems improperly phrased. Your concern is not *really* with the return value; it is with the second parameter `default_st`. That's where this whole notion of "*constructor, copy constructor and destructor, even if second (default) argument is not selected for return*". You want to somehow take this parameter and choose to construct a `std::string` from it or not based on the first parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I understood the combinations of requirements but:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

// if called with an rvalue (xvalue) as 2:nd arg, move or copy
std::string get_or_default(const std::string& st, std::string&& default_st) {
    std::cout << "got temporary\n";
    if(st.empty())
        return std::move(default_st);      // rval, move ctor
        // return std::forward<std::string>(default_st); // alternative
    else
        return st;                         // lval, copy ctor
}

// lvalue as 2:nd argument, return the reference as-is
const std::string& get_or_default(const std::string& st,
                                  const std::string& default_st) {
    std::cout << "got ref\n";
    if(st.empty()) return default_st;
    else           return st;
}

int main() {
    std::string lval = "lval";

    // get ref or copy ...
    decltype(auto) s1 = get_or_default("", "temporary1");
    decltype(auto) s2 = get_or_default("", std::string("temporary2"));
    decltype(auto) s3 = get_or_default("", lval);

    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    std::cout << std::is_reference_v<decltype(s1)> << "\n";
    std::cout << std::is_reference_v<decltype(s2)> << "\n";
    std::cout << std::is_reference_v<decltype(s3)> << "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
got temporary
got temporary
got ref
false
false
true
```

Edit: Made a slightly more generic version after OP:s testing. It can use a lambda, like
`auto empty_check = [](const std::string& s) { return s.empty(); };`
to test if the first argument is empty.

```
template<typename T, typename F>
T get_or_default(const T& st, T&& default_st, F empty) {
    if(empty(st)) return std::move(default_st);
               // return std::forward<T>(default_st); // alternative
    else          return st;
}

template<typename T, typename F>
const T& get_or_default(const T& st, const T& default_st, F empty) {
    if(empty(st)) return default_st;
    else          return st;
}
```

Comment: Ted, thanks a lot for your solution! First argument should always be lvalue (as in the question), but this is very simple to fix. A bigger problem is that in first function std::move() does not work. Copy constructor and destructor are called instead of returning a reference to lvalue.

As you have already brilliantly solved the case with second argument being lvalue, we can now think that first argument is always lvalue and second argument is always rvalue. What could be a most performance-effective strategy to cope without copy constructors?

Comment: I'm sorry if I could not explain better. Please see the example code, which shows that copy constructor is called instead of move constructor: https://onlinegdb.com/rkMKP1Gir
I had to replace std::string with a debug class TStruct to show which constructors were called (see case "First  2")

Comment: I added more debugging output and now it is visible that copy constructor is being called in "First 2" case (see "Cc(4)" string in output). Can we avoid it? I added comments at lines 75-77, 80-82: https://godbolt.org/z/y74sDG

Comment: @Rualark Updated with the new function templates: https://godbolt.org/z/JKK-PP
To answer your questions: No, not that I can see. When one of the optional parameters is an xvalue we must create a "body" for it to be moved into. We can't change the return type of the function depending on runtime conditions.

Comment: Ted, thank you so much for your answers! This answer seems perfect except the copy constructor problem. P.S. For some reason I cannot mention you using @Ted

Comment: Probably, this could be an impassable limitation of C++ that a function cannot return value or reference based on runtime decision.

Comment: @Rualark Indeed it is. To emulate that one can use `std::variant` as mentioned in the comments but I doubt it'll be more effective.

Answer (score 2):

Well, there a few things here.
To express what you ask for directly you can use something like `std::variant<std::string, std::string&>` as your function return type. Although I have not checked if variant can store a reference. 
Or some equivalent from a third party library. either<> ?
You can also write your own class wrapping string and string ref.

(Not an real code)

```cpp
struct StringOrRef {
    enum class Type {Value, Ref} type;
    union {
        std::string value;
        std::reference_wrapper<const std::string> ref;
    };
...
};
```

Check the topic: discriminating union in C++.

But I think there is a bigger problem with your example!
Please consider the ownership of data. std::string takes ownership of data passed. That is why it copy data. Thus when your function returns - the called is sure it had a data and don't need to worry about it as long as (s)he holds the value.

In case you design a function to return a reference to passed argument value - you need to make sure that the value is used within the same lifespan as the argument passed (to which the ref is returned)

So consider:

```cpp
StringOrRef func(strging const& a, string const& b);
...

StringOrRef val;
{ // begin scope:


SomeStruct s = get_defaul();
val = func("some value", s.get_ref_to_internal_string());

}// end of val scope

val; // is in scope but may be referencing freed data.
```

The problem here is the temporary object `SomeStruct s`. if it's member function `get_ref_to_internal_string() -> string&` returns a ref to a string field of that object (which is often the way it is implemented) - then when `s` goes out of scope - tha ref becomes invalid. that is - it is referencing freed memory which may have been given to some other objects.
And if you capture that reference in `val` - val will be referencing invalid data.
You will be lucky if it all end in `access violation` or a signal. At worst your program continues but will be crashing randomly.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for you suggested solution! Now I understand that I am looking for an elegant solution, that will be simple for caller. I have not seen such syntax before. Is this correct? enum {
std::string s;
std::String& v;
};

Comment: Ah - I made a few typos in the answer which I have fixed.

Currect syntax is `union {std::string s; std::string& v}`; The concept explained in [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union) in C/C++ section.
Also, [this article](https://medium.com/@almtechhub/c-c-tagged-discriminated-union-ecd5907610bf) seems to give a good example too.

But just to be clear - I don't think it is a good approach :)

Comment: [Unions cannot have nonstatic member varialbes of reference type.](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.union#3.sentence-4). [Nor `std::variant` objects.](http://eel.is/c++draft/variant#variant-2).

Comment: It's worth mentioning that one can use std::reference_wrapper<> instead of direct reference. And let us not forget the need to define constructors and destructor if one was to implement such a class. That is why I think it is a bad idea to do it. 

But if anyone wants to experiment with the concept - here is a [godbolt playground](https://godbolt.org/z/_5z-2-).